# Ideal generator of a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Assume J is a non-zero ideal of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]= \{a+b\alpha:a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$ I'm trying to prove that there exists a positive integer $n$ in J, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: What is $\alpha$? Or, more importantly, what is $\alpha^2$? Because that doesn't immediately seem to be of the form $a+b\alpha$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. $\alpha^2=m, m \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What do you say if $J = (0) = \{0\}$?

Comment: I'm trying to prove the non-zero case though, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Let $\beta$ be any non zero element in your ideal $J$. Can you prove that $\beta$ is algebraic on $\mathbb Z$ ? Considering the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $\mathbb Z$, can you find a non-zero integer which must belong to $J$ ?  (NB: you only need to know that $\alpha$ is algebraic in order to solve this exercise. The fact that its degree is $2$ does not matter.)

Comment: should I suppose $J$ is generated by an element in $\mathbb{Z}$, and say this element is $a_1+b_1 \alpha$, then if $ab_1+ba_1$ is zero, I'll have a positive integer in $J$?

Comment: Maybe we can use the theorem that the norm of any ideal is contained in the ideal.

Comment: Do you know that $\,\alpha^2 = m\,$ is not the square of an integer?

Answer (score 0):

I assume $\alpha \in \mathbb C$. Let $z = a + b\alpha$ be a non-zero element of an ideal $J$. Set $w = a - b\alpha$.

1. When $w = 0$.
   As $a = b\alpha$, we have $J \ni z = 2a \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$. So $z$ or $-z$ is what you're looking for.
2. When $w \neq 0$.
   Then $J \ni zw = a^2 - b^2\alpha^2 \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$. So $zw$ or $-zw$ does the job.

Added. If you're familiar with algebraic number theory, an approach suggested by Suzet and Alexandros would be better. This solution is too elementary that one might miss essence.